# Using variables in __init__ method in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been given a Python module where I have a class named 'Node'. The `__init__` method inside the class is given below:

```
def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
    self.fata = data
    self._next = next
```

I want to know how this would differ if I simply mention data and next as variables and don't assign them to None? Like this:

```
def __init__(self, data, next):
    self.fata = data
    self._next = next
```

Comment: What happens if you do it as such?   The top will set a default value if it is not supplied.  If you dont supply a default value, what is `fata` and `_next` if you try to access it after you instantiate node?

Comment: Actually the second line in each block of the code, I meant `self.data = data`.

Comment: Did you try it out? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
        self._data = data
        self._next = next

class B:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self._data = data
        self._next = next
```

Then, e.g.:

```
>>> x = A(1,2)
>>> y = B(1,2)
>>> #no difference so far, but
>>> z = A()
>>> w = B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    w = B()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'data' and 'next'
```

Missing required arguments are a run-time error. They don't default to `None`.